# mongodb filter where property not ends with

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongodb collection with documents structured like this

```
{
   ...
   "ownerName":"Bob",   
   "city":"Oregon",
   "refNote":"sadkj1233233@qwertz",
}
```

I want to filter and select only documents where refNote not ends with `@qwertz`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use regular expression and `$not` operator,

- `$regex` to pass string that you want to search, specify `$` at the end of string to search exact from end of the string,
- `$not` to check opposit condition

```
db.collection.find({
  refNote: {
    $not: {
      $regex: "@qwertz$"
    }
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nvEEYUX42Zc)